# Automation Studio - I need Data Extract file UTF8 Without BOM

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, data-export, sftp, encoding

In our automation we are creating a txt file with all of our unsubscribes and put it on our SFTP server. Now the problem is that the data extract activity in SFMC automation says that the file is converted to UTF-8 but it actually converts to UTF-8 BOM. Our system is not set up to handle UTF-8 BOM and what we need is only UTF-8.

Does anyone know how to get around this issue in SFMC? In the automation in the acitivity data extract we have set it up in such a way to convert to UTF-8 so not sure why it's doing BOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask Salesforce support to provision an additional Data Extract to your account. There are multiple ones available, which are not implicitly shown in Automation Studio, and there for sure is one which can provide you with an UTF-8 without BOM.